# MVC4 Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have several projects referencing the controllers from an external project within the routing. So, projects A, B, and C share the controllers in Core project D.

Project A and B work perfectly, but for project C, the routing will work and redirect but the URL will not rewrite to match the route.

```
Here is an example of a custom route and the default route:
   routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                "AssistedLivingByLocation", // Route name
                "Assisted-Living/{state}/{city}/{zip}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "AssistedLiving", action = "Results", zip = UrlParameter.Optional }// } ;

routes.MapRouteLowercase(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Core.Controllers" }
        );
```

The Assisted Living controller is being called and the state and city params are being passed. The resulting partial view is being displayed, but the URL is not being rewritten. Like I said, all this same code works in the other two projects.

What am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean by URL re-written?  what is the URL you get and what is the URL you want.  Also the code above just detects routes, this does not write any URL or routes ?

Comment: I have a base controller and action ('/base/searchcare') that redirects to the above route with all the correct parameters, but doesn't rewrite the url and it stays at '/base/searchcare'.

Comment: then you need to provide the code you are using to redirect to the desired route, or delivery your search results from a single source block via Ajax cal or something, don't other complicate things

Comment: The same code works in two other web sites, so it has to be some setting within route configuration that i'm missing.

Comment: THis is my redirect code for the route:                                    return RedirectToRoute("AssistedLivingByLocation", new { State = state, City = city });